# AsycTask Skipping frames. Not updating UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using async task to download file from the server,
during file download i will show progress using needle.
Inside an async task i am calling publish progress method.

```
         while (true) {
                        final int read = inputStream.read(readArray);
                        if (read <= 0) {
                        break;
                        }
                       totalRead+= read;
                       this.publishProgress(String.valueOf(100L * totalRead/ contentLength));
                     }
```

But as stated

> onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call
>   to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>   undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>   user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>   For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>   a text field.

it is not updating on exact time.
i am trying to change the needle angle in onProgressUpdate method by passing desired rotation angle value.

```
 final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 matrix.postRotate((float) (rotaionAngle));
 this.needleImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap
                   .createBitmap(this.pointerBitmap, 0, 0,
                                this.pointerBitmap.getWidth(),
                                this.pointerBitmap.getHeight(),
                                matrix, true));
```

But it is not executing every time .frames are getting skipped skipping warning is coming.

> skipped 100 frames application may be doing too much work on its main
>   thread

How can i resolve so that it should not miss an update in GUI?

Comment: you cannot change gui during AsycTask in doinBackground. You have to shoe your progres before the doIn background. Show it on onPreExecute() and dismiss it on onPostExecute() method.

Comment: @Cüneyt i need to display the progress during download only (doInBackground). :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything within the onProgressUpdate method is on the main thread. This part takes too long:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(
    this.pointerBitmap,
    0, 
    0,
    this.pointerBitmap.getWidth(),
    this.pointerBitmap.getHeight(),
    matrix, 
    true)
);
```

Avoid expensive operations like this on the main thread, instead consider creating the bitmap within the async task. Consider something like this:

```
private class AsyncTaskExample extends AsyncTask<Void, Bitmap, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            if(values.length >0){
                needleImage.setImageBitmap(values[0]);
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //do some stuff


            final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            while (true) {
                final int read = inputStream.read(readArray);
                if (read <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                totalRead+= read;

                matrix.reset();
                matrix.postRotate(100L * totalRead/ contentLength);

                publishProgress(
                    Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        this.pointerBitmap,        // keep a copy of the bitmap within the asynctask so you can access it 
                        0, 
                        0,
                        this.pointerBitmap.getWidth(),
                        this.pointerBitmap.getHeight(),
                        matrix, 
                        true
                    )
                );
            }

            // do some stuff
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

However, further to this topic, you'll get much better performance if you can make a custom class that does its own drawing rather than creating bitmaps all the time.

Comment: Thanks joe. I will try to implement your suggestion. If possible can you please provide any link to proceed further or any alternative where i can use handler/thread to update UI if possible.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at creating a custom view for your needle image. 
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: You're aiming to only ever load two bitmaps: the background and the needle. Your custom view would draw the background, rotate the canvas, draw the needle, and restore the canvas in its onDraw() method

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create new Bitmap every time you want to show progress. Try to rotate ImageView instead.